# How to save values from dynamic input fields along with non dynamic with php?

Tags: php, html

So here is my html

```
<form method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Firstname">Firstname</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter firstname">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Lastname">Lastname</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter lastname">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Contact">Contact</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Contact" name="contact" placeholder="Enter contact number">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Email">Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email address">
            </div>




         </div> 


 <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Username">Username</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Username" name="username" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" name="password" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="form-group">
              <label for="CPassword">Confirm Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="CPassword" name="cpassword" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            </div>
         </div> 
    </div>  
  </div>
   <div class="col-lg-12">

   <table class="table">
            <tbody id="newlinehere">
            <tr>
              <th>Day</th>
              <th>Start</th>
              <th>End</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="countme">
              <td>
              <div class="form-group">

              <select class="form-control" name="day[]">
                <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
                <option  value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
                <option  value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
                <option  value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
                <option  value="Friday">Friday</option>
                <option  value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
                <option  value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
              </select>
            </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                    <div class="bootstrap-timepicker"><div class="bootstrap-timepicker-widget dropdown-menu"><table><tbody><tr><td><a href="#" data-action="incrementHour"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></a></td><td class="separator">&nbsp;</td><td><a href="#" data-action="incrementMinute"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></a></td><td class="separator">&nbsp;</td><td class="meridian-column"><a href="#" data-action="toggleMeridian"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></a></td></tr><tr><td><span class="bootstrap-timepicker-hour">12</span></td> <td class="separator">:</td><td><span class="bootstrap-timepicker-minute">15</span></td> <td class="separator">&nbsp;</td><td><span class="bootstrap-timepicker-meridian">AM</span></td></tr><tr><td><a href="#" data-action="decrementHour"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></a></td><td class="separator"></td><td><a href="#" data-action="decrementMinute"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></a></td><td class="separator">&nbsp;</td><td><a href="#" data-action="toggleMeridian"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></a></td></tr></tbody></table></div>
            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" name="start[]">

                <div class="input-group-addon">
                  <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                    <div class="bootstrap-timepicker"><div class="bootstrap-timepicker-widget dropdown-menu"><table><tbody><tr><td><a href="#" data-action="incrementHour"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></a></td><td class="separator">&nbsp;</td><td><a href="#" data-action="incrementMinute"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></a></td><td class="separator">&nbsp;</td><td class="meridian-column"><a href="#" data-action="toggleMeridian"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></a></td></tr><tr><td><span class="bootstrap-timepicker-hour">12</span></td> <td class="separator">:</td><td><span class="bootstrap-timepicker-minute">15</span></td> <td class="separator">&nbsp;</td><td><span class="bootstrap-timepicker-meridian">AM</span></td></tr><tr><td><a href="#" data-action="decrementHour"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></a></td><td class="separator"></td><td><a href="#" data-action="decrementMinute"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></a></td><td class="separator">&nbsp;</td><td><a href="#" data-action="toggleMeridian"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></a></td></tr></tbody></table></div>
            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" name="end[]">

                <div class="input-group-addon">
                  <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
              </td>
             <td>
             <!--<button type="button" class="btn removeline">x</button>-->
             </td>
            </tr>

          </tbody></table>



   </div>

   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="newline">New Line</button>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="testsave">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

AND here is my php code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["testsave"])){

    $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
    $contact=$_POST['contact'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $cpassword=$_POST['cpassword'];
    $day=$_POST['day'];
    $start=$_POST['start'];
    $end=$_POST['end'];
    $number = count($_POST["day"]);


    $sql = "SELECT coalesce(MAX(cashier_id), 0) AS maxx FROM tbl_cashiers";
    $result = $DBcon->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $cashier_id=$row["maxx"];
    }
        $cashier_id++;
    } else {
        $cashier_id=1;
    }





        if($number > 0){




                foreach( $day as $key => $n ) {


                    $dday=$day[$key];
                    $sstart=$start[$key];
                    $eend=$end[$key];

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_shifts (cashier_id, shift_day, shift_start,shift_end)
                    VALUES ('$cashier_id','$dday','$sstart','$eend')";

                    if ($DBcon->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    } 

                }
/*  $sql2 = "INSERT INTO tbl_cashiers (username, password, firstname,lastname, contact, email)
                VALUES ('$username','$password','$firstname','$lastname','$contact','$email')";
                if ($DBcon->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
                    $last_id = $DBcon->insert_id;
                }  */

        }
    }

    ?>
```

Notice the commented code. I would like to save these data into two tables but having this way only saves the first array for the DAY,START,and END values.
I'm thinking why putting this at the end of the foreach loop stops the looping. Please enlighten me.

PS: The commented code is actually not commented here, i just emphasized it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand your problem, insert query for days is not working?

Carefull for SQL injection without prepared statement.

You can use helpers like this one:

```
<?php
class DB
{
    protected static $instance = null;

    protected function __construct() {}
    protected function __clone() {}

    public static function instance($context = 'stream')
    {
        //DB Dispatch
        if (!isset(self::$instance[$context]) || self::$instance[$context] === null)
        {
            $opt  = array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => FALSE,
            );
            switch ($context)
            {
                case 'stream':
                        $dsn = 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset='.DB_CHAR;
                        self::$instance[$context] = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $opt);
                    break;
                default:
                        die('DB Context invalid');
                    break;
            }
        }
        return self::$instance[$context];
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array(self::instance(), $method), $args);
    }

    public static function query($sql, $args = [], $context = 'stream')
    { 
        $stmt = self::instance($context)->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }
    public static function getLastInsertedId($context)
    {
        return self::instance($context)->lastInsertId();
    }
    public static function insert($table, $keyValue, $context)
    {
        $fieldString = '';
        $valueString = '';
        $i           = 1;
        foreach ($keyValue as $key => $currKeyValue) 
        {
            $fieldString .= $key;
            $valueString .= ':'.$key;
            if($i != count($keyValue))
            {
                $fieldString .= ', ';
                $valueString .= ', ';
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $query       = 'INSERT INTO `'.$table.'` ('.$fieldString.') VALUES('.$valueString.')';
        DB::query($query, $keyValue, $context);
    }
    public static function update($table, $keyValue, $idtoUpdate, $context = 'stream', $fieldIdToUpdate = 'id')
    {
        $updateString   = '';
        $i              = 1;
        foreach ($keyValue as $key => $currKeyValue) 
        {
            $updateString .= $key.'=:'.$key;
            if($i != count($keyValue))
                $updateString .= ', ';
            $i++;
        }
        $query          = 'UPDATE `'.$table.'` SET '.$updateString.' WHERE '.$fieldIdToUpdate.'=:id';
        $keyValue['id'] = $idtoUpdate;
        DB::query($query, $keyValue, $context);
    }
    public static function select($table, $where = false, $whereParams = array(), $selectFields = '*', $context = 'stream', $fetchAll = false)
    {
        $selectQuery        = 'SELECT '.$selectFields.' FROM '.$table;
        if($where)
            $selectQuery .= ' WHERE '.$where;
        $return = DB::query($selectQuery, $whereParams, $context);
        if(!$fetchAll)
            return $return;
        else
            return $return->fetchAll();
    }
    /**
    *@param string $table : Table used for the search
    *@param string $where : String containing the "WHERE" part of the query
    *@param array $whereParams : Parameters to bind
    *@param string $context : DB context (for multiple DB)
    */
    public static function checkIfExist($table, $where = false, $whereParams = array(), $context = 'stream')
    {
        if(empty(DB::select($table, $where, $whereParams, '*', $context, true)))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    public static function getLatestId()
    {
        return self::instance()->lastInsertId();
    }
}
?>
```